# PHP SOAP Client Woes

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have a basic knowledge of SOAP using PHP but am getting stuck on what I hope turns out to be one of those "DUH" moments.

I have a WSDL file that I use to retrieve information from a remote site and have been using it as such:-

```
$ordernumber = 171994;
$username = "someone@somewhere.com";
$password = "secret";
$arr = array("orderNumber" => $ordernumber,"orderReference" => '');

$client = new SoapClient(BASEPATH."/feed/Orders.wsdl",array('trace' => 1));
$orders = $client->RetrieveOrder ($username,$password,'',array("orderElements" => $arr));
```

That works fine for single orders and I get the information I want.  However, If I want to retrieve multiple orders then I am running through a foreach loop sending a single request for each order.

According to the documentation I should be able to provide an array of orders and retrieve multiple orders in one go, and, if I use the online tool http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html and enter multiple orders then I get the expected result.  The xml request that gets generated from soapclient.com is as follows:-

```
<email xsi:type="xsd:string">someone@somewhere.com</email>
<password xsi:type="xsd:string">secret</password>
<messageHeader xsi:type="tns:messageHeaderElement">
<senderId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
<receiverId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
<messageId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
<transactionId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
<transactionTimeStamp xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"/>
</messageHeader>
<orderElements xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:queryElement[2]">
<item xsi:type="tns:queryElement">
<orderReference xsi:type="xsd:int"/>
<orderNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">171994</orderNumber>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:queryElement">
<orderReference xsi:type="xsd:int"/>
<orderNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">172101</orderNumber>
</item>
</orderElements>
```

The messageHeader section is optional and I am just sending '' in the above call.

Can anyone please tell me how, using PHP SOAPCLIENT that I can send one single request for multiple orders?

Thanking you in advance :-)

EDIT:

Thanks @DeaconDesperado and @EM-Creations for your repsonses.  @DeaconDesperado is right - I should be able to use the $client->VendaRetrieveOrder method.  I have tried many ways to generate the orderElements array, the following is the most recent and in my eyes the nearest...

```
$orderElements = 
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [orderNumber] => 236431
        [orderReference] => 
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [orderNumber] => 236431
        [orderReference] => 
    )
)

$orders = $client->VendaRetrieveOrder ($username,$password,'',array("orderElements" => $orderElements));
```

But, when I use that then I get the following trapped error.

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'orderReference' property
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using $client->__soapCall() ? http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: @EM-Creations it shouldn't be necessary to call the low-level `__soapCall()` method directly, its obfuscated with underscores for a reason... that is a utility that allows callables from the WSDL to be used directly on the client object, as @l0ckm4 is trying to do with `RetrieveOrder`.

Comment: @l0ckm4 What does your query array look like when attempting to get multiple orders?  The above code is just looking for one numbered order and wouldn't help us uncover a problem.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado Please see comments above.  Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: @EM-Creations Thanks I will have a look at the ___soapCall method but I think the issue is how I am compiling the array.  I think I just need to get the orderElements built correctly. I would prefer to use the $client->RetrieveOrder method over the ___soapCall if possible

Comment: @l0ckm4 - are we certain `orderReference` is not required by the query spec?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado 100% sure. i never specify it on a single call, only send it empty as in first code example

Comment: Ah fair enough; hope you've got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using lots functionality in your provided API use this.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2php/

I used it on previous project saved me a lot of time.